# How should i implement authentication/authorization with multiple models using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have 3 kind of users in my app: **Club, Person, and Admin**. Each one is very different from each other, which means they almost don't share any attributes except for the authentication data, so that's why i'd rather use **3 different models**. Also, i want to enable a single authentication model for all these kinds of users, using **Authlogic**, and handle Authorization using **CanCan**.

Initially i thought of something like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # This class has the email and password in order to be authenticated with Authlogic
end
```

And for each one i would have

```
class Club < User end
class Admin < User end
```

But then the User table would be cluttered with all the columns of the other kinds of users and they will remain null.

Another option would be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # This class has the email and password in order to be authenticated with Authlogic
 belongs_to :role, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And for each kind of user, a role would be assigned. The problem is that accessing the properties of the method would be something like `user.role.logo`. One way i can think to solve this is by using delegate but still i don't know if that's the best option.

**The question is, how would you suggest me to implement this? What would be the best way?**

Comment: do you really need 3 different models? I mean for other reason than Authorization...

Comment: The reason is that the 3 kind of users are very different one from each other, so i wouldn't like a single model with a bunch of NULL fields in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you suggest, I would create a User model to handle authentication. Then you can create a one-to-one polymorphic relationship between the User model and your roles' models. Your User model will have to include role_type (which is a string) and role_id (which is an integer) attributes.

#### User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role, :polymorphic => true
end
```

#### Admin.rb

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :role
end
```

You can test what class a user's role is and access its attributes. For example:

```
User.first.role.is_a? Admin
=> true
User.first.role.last_name
=> "Smith"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to achieve role based authorization. Have a look at the wiki page in 
cancan.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization